# How to call the instance method of the parent class?

Tags: python, class, super

I found a way, as follows instance :

Change the instance method to the class method to achieve the result I want.

```
class MyClassA:
    name = 'MyClassA'

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'instance name'
        self.print_name()
        pass

    @classmethod
    def print_name(cls):
        name = cls.name
        print(name)

    @classmethod
    def init(cls):
        cls.name = 'class name'


class MyClassB(MyClassA):
    pass


MyClassB.init()
c1 = MyClassB()
```

---

I want to set `MyClassB.name='class name'` and get `MyClassB.name`.

How to modify the code?

```
class MyClassA:
    name = 'MyClassA'

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'instance name'
        self.print_name()
        pass

    def print_name(self):
        name = super().name
        print(name)

    @classmethod
    def init(cls):
        cls.name = 'class name'


class MyClassB(MyClassA):
    pass


MyClassB.init()
c1 = MyClassB()
```

---

I want to call the method `c1.print_name()` of the parent class instance in the subclass.

How to modify the code to get the output:`'class name'`

My code is as follows:

```
class MyClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.print_name()
        pass

    def print_name(self):
        name = super().name
        print(name)

    @classmethod
    def init(cls):
        cls.name = 'class name'


class MyClassB(MyClassA):
    pass


MyClassB.init()
c1 = MyClassB()
```

The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-0a688d5bfaa6>", line 20, in <module>
    c1 = MyClassB()
  File "<ipython-input-3-0a688d5bfaa6>", line 3, in __init__
    self.print_name()
  File "<ipython-input-3-0a688d5bfaa6>", line 7, in print_name
    name = super().name
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: this is somewhat unusual. what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @anon01  I want to set `MyClassB.name='class name'`,how to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super().name` is looking for an attribute called `name` on the parent class - i.e. `MyClassA` - which obviously doesn't exist.

Since you have added the attribute `name` to `MyClassB` you should access it as `self.name` - e.g.:

```
class MyClassA:
    def __init__(self):
        self.print_name()
        pass

    def print_name(self):
        name = self.name
        print(name)

    @classmethod
    def init(cls):
        cls.name = 'class name'


class MyClassB(MyClassA):
    pass
```

To answer your new 'upper' question, if you want to set a specific `name` attribute, which defaults to `a` but becomes `b` for `MyClassB` then you need to override this when instantiating:

```
class MyClassB(MyClassA):
    def __init__(self):
        # Call the parent class' super method (sets name == a)
        super().__init__()
        # Override name
        self.name = 'b'
```

Comment: If the class attribute name is different from the instance attribute name, how should I write it?

Comment: You can always reference class attributes explicitly, i.e. `MyClassB.name` (or `type(self).name`), but if you have `name` defined on both the class and instances, I might argue that's a design flaw.

Comment: I revised my question.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo The properties of the class and instance may be different.

Comment: `self.name = a` will override `cls.name` when `__init__` is called. If you want this attribute set differently for each class, you will need to set it in a custom `__init__` for each class inheriting from `MyClassA` after calling `super()` to get he 'default.

Comment: @match I want to set `MyClassB.name='class name'`,how to do ?

Comment: Have updated my answer with what I think you want

Comment: I have found a way, thank you for your enlightenment. Because you are the only answer, I will accept it first.